# Javascript calling function - onclick works whereas onload doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, onload

I am trying to display an offer when the page loads.

The offer works and displays using the `onClick` method (meaning there is nothing wrong with the `'getOffers.php'` script:

```
<div class="container" onclick="getRequest('<?=$root?>getOffers.php')">

    <div id="offers" class="home-box">
        <h3>Offers</h3>
        <p id="target"></p>
    </div><!-- /#offers -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

Whenever i try:

```
<div class="container" onload="getRequest('<?=$root?>getOffers.php')">
```

it doesn't seem to work, could somebody kindly tell my what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put the `onload` call on the `<body>` element or just put it in a `<script>` tag below the `div`

```
<div class="container">
...
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
     getRequest('<?=$root?>getOffers.php');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onload , onload is an event of the window. You cannot use it on a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

The "load" event is not fired for `<div>` elements. You can wait for the "load" event at the `<body>` or document or window.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = function(){
   // do your stuff...
}
```

Note that if you override onload function, you will lose your previous assignement.

Answer (score 0):

try to call onload of body of html

```
<body onload="getRequest('<?=$root?>getOffers.php')">
```

**The `onload event` occurs when an object has been loaded.**

`onload` is most often used within the `<body>` element to execute a script once a web page has completely loaded all content (including images, script files, CSS files, etc.).
so you can't apply it on the `div`

---

<kbd>http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event3.shtml</kbd>